# Why does this rackup file work with Thin, but not WEBrick or Unicorn?

Tags: ruby, rack, thin, webrick, unicorn

I am having a strange issue running my static website locally (for testing).
Both WEBrick and Unicorn are causing an assertion failure in Rack when navigating to root. However Thin works
perfectly.

My rackup file 'config.ru':

```
# This is the root of our app
@root = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)) + '/site'
default_charset = "; charset=UTF-8"

run Proc.new { |env|

    # Extract the requested path from the request
    path = Rack::Utils.unescape(env['PATH_INFO'])
    index_file = @root + "#{path}/index.html"

    if File.exists?(index_file)
        # Return the index
        [200, {'Content-Type' => 'text/html' + default_charset}, File.read(index_file)]
    else
        # Pass the request to the directory app
        response = Rack::Directory.new(@root).call(env)
        if response[1]['Content-Type']
            response[1]['Content-Type'] += default_charset
        end
        response
    end
}
```

Gem list is as follows:

```
$ bundle exec gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.0.18)
coderay (0.9.8)
daemons (1.1.4)
erector (0.8.3)
eventmachine (0.12.10)
kgio (2.6.0)
kramdown (0.13.3)
polyglot (0.3.2)
rack (1.3.2)
raindrops (0.7.0)
rake (0.9.2)
thin (1.2.11)
treetop (1.4.10)
unicorn (4.1.1)
```

And these are the errors I get:

```
$ bundle exec rackup
[2011-09-12 21:19:50] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2011-09-12 21:19:50] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2010-08-18) [x86_64-linux]
[2011-09-12 21:19:50] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2556 port=9292
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Sep/2011 21:20:05] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0027
[2011-09-12 21:20:05] ERROR Rack::Lint::LintError: Response body must respond to each
        /home/scott/development/test/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/lint.rb:19:in `assert'
        /home/scott/development/test/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/lint.rb:513:in `each'
        /home/scott/development/test/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/body_proxy.rb:26:in `method_missing'
        /home/scott/development/test/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/chunked.rb:23:in `each'
        /home/scott/development/test/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:71:in `service'
        /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
        /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
        /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'

$ bundle exec unicorn
I, [2011-09-12T21:20:33.219694 #2567]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:8080 fd=3
I, [2011-09-12T21:20:33.219883 #2567]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
I, [2011-09-12T21:20:33.220771 #2567]  INFO -- : master process ready
I, [2011-09-12T21:20:33.221535 #2570]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=2570
I, [2011-09-12T21:20:33.221787 #2570]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2011-09-12T21:20:33.253184 #2570]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Sep/2011 21:20:41] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0030
E, [2011-09-12T21:20:41.087884 #2570] ERROR -- : app error: Response body must respond to each (Rack::Lint::LintError)
E, [2011-09-12T21:20:41.087935 #2570] ERROR -- : /home/scott/development/test/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/lint.rb:19:in `assert'
E, [2011-09-12T21:20:41.087968 #2570] ERROR -- : /home/scott/development/test/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/lint.rb:513:in `each'
E, [2011-09-12T21:20:41.087991 #2570] ERROR -- : /home/scott/development/test/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/body_proxy.rb:26:in `method_missing'
E, [2011-09-12T21:20:41.088013 #2570] ERROR -- : /home/scott/development/test/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/chunked.rb:23:in `each'
E, [2011-09-12T21:20:41.088035 #2570] ERROR -- : /home/scott/development/test/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.1.1/lib/unicorn/http_response.rb:41:in `http_response_write'
E, [2011-09-12T21:20:41.088057 #2570] ERROR -- : /home/scott/development/test/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.1.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:536:in `process_client'
E, [2011-09-12T21:20:41.088078 #2570] ERROR -- : /home/scott/development/test/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.1.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:600:in `worker_loop'
E, [2011-09-12T21:20:41.088100 #2570] ERROR -- : /home/scott/development/test/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.1.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:485:in `spawn_missing_workers'
E, [2011-09-12T21:20:41.088124 #2570] ERROR -- : /home/scott/development/test/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.1.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:135:in `start'
E, [2011-09-12T21:20:41.088147 #2570] ERROR -- : /home/scott/development/test/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.1.1/bin/unicorn:121:in `<top (required)>'
E, [2011-09-12T21:20:41.088168 #2570] ERROR -- : /home/scott/development/test/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:19:in `load'
E, [2011-09-12T21:20:41.088190 #2570] ERROR -- : /home/scott/development/test/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:19:in `<main>'
```

And thin working fine:

```
$bundle exec thin start
>> Using rack adapter
>> Thin web server (v1.2.11 codename Bat-Shit Crazy)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
^C>> Stopping ...
```

Why is this happening, when all three servers are supposed to adhere to the
Rack specification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are all three running on ruby 1.9?

If you check out the rack spec (found here: http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/SPEC.html) under the body section it says:

The Body must respond to each and must only yield String values. The Body itself should not be an instance of String, as this will break in Ruby 1.9.

So according to the spec i'd guess either thin is a little slacker in checking it responds to each or perhaps theres a difference in the ruby versions?

Comment: Yep, just wrap the `File.read(index_file)` in an array and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks to you both, especially Benoit for the fix. I knew it would be something simple like that! :-) All working now.